# Writing a function from a contour plot?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

So, I had a weird dream. I was lost in this dark, dreary, swamp. In order to leave the swamp this wizard dude said I had to figure out three riddles, and this was the first one:

["Write the function (or functions) that produce(s) these circles."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emat4.png)

That was all the information he gave. Before I knew it, he was gone. Pretty unhelpful wizard.

This doesn't even seem possible with ordinary univariate functions. I remember in the dream I was trying to figure out something with sine waves (even Euler's theorem for imaginary numbers at one point) but to no avail. Long story short, dream-me is stuck in the swamp for all eternity trying to figure this out. So now I'm trying to think of the problem in the context of multivariable functions.

My background in multivariable calculus is pretty basic but I feel pretty comfortable with partial derivatives and integrals. I'm wondering whether this is just a matter of thinking about the behavior of multivariable functions or maybe setting some unknown function equal to some arbitrary constant z-value, but I honestly wouldn't know where to begin.

I'm also tagging this as a linear-algebra and an ODE question in the possibility that I could view these circles not as contour plots of a single function but as separate periodic trajectories for some system of equations.

**What would be the process for solving something like this? Is this impossible, and if so, can I prove it is?** The sooner I solve this the sooner I can get to the wizard's next riddle.

Comment: Great story....

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you can't have an equation of the form $y = f(x)$, because for a given $x$ may correspond to two $y$ values, or none.

But you could use an implicit function.  If these are circles (with different scales on the $x$ and $y$ axes) you might try something of the form

$$ \prod_{i=1}^5 ((x - x_i)^2 +  y^2 - r_i^2) = 0$$

where $(x - x_i)^2 + y^2 = r_i^2$ is the equation for circle number $i$, having centre $(x_i, 0)$ and radius $r_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Series of ellipses shown together can be altered for whatever detail:

[image]

```
a = 2 ; (* 2,3,5,7 *);
g2 = ContourPlot [
  10 (x - 2 a)^2/ a^2 + y^2/a^2 == 4, {x, -2, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic]
Show[{g2, g3, g5, g7}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.9]
```